# Find closest node with attribute

Tags: python, networkx

I have a large networkx network where I want to find the closest node (by edge weight, recursively) with a attribute set to True. Can I do this without looping over nodes?

Comment: You'll have to do some kind of graph traversal.  Have you tried networkx.bfs_edges()?

Comment: Ideally they would also be ordered by weight if I have to loop through them myself. Also I want nodes, not edges.